# NSPredicate and CoreData?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

The query works fine if directly added to a predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"author == %@", author];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

The query doesn't work if created and then passed to a predicate

Is there a solution? I rather not pass the predicate itself to the method

**Author is a subclass of NSManagedObject**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "%@"'

[self fetchObjectsWithQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"author == %@", author];

- (void)fetchObjectsWithQuery:(NSString *)query
{
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@", query];
   [request setPredicate:predicate];
   [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format strings work differently in

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"author == %@", author] // (1)
```

and

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"author == %@", author]
```

In particular the placeholders "%@" and "%K" have different meanings.

(1) produces a *string* of the form

```
"author == <textual description of author object>"
```

which you cannot use in

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@", query];
```

So you cannot pre-format predicates as strings. Another example to demonstrate the problem:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"author == nil"]
```

works, but

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:"%@", @"author == nil"]
```

does not.

Answer (score 0):

There's no good reason not to create and pass around `NSPredicate` objects. There are ways to do exactly what you want to do, but they are either less expressive than just using predicates or will require you to duplicate the logic underlying `NSPredicate`.