# Using regex in NSPredicate to perform a NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, regex, swift, core-data

I try to perform an `NSFetchRequest` with this `NSPredicate`:

```
let searchString: NSString = "приш[её]л"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "text MATCHES[cd] %@", searchString)
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Data")
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

do {
    let objects = try context!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
    return objects
} catch {
    print("Error")
}
```

But no results, though actually 'text' contains "пришёл"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found answer in this qustion: [Setting up a CoreData regular expression predicate for a comma-separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180308/setting-up-a-coredata-regular-expression-predicate-for-a-comma-separated-list)

```
let searchString = "приш[её]л"
let format = "(text MATCHES %@)"
let pattern = NSString(format: ".*(\\b%@\\b).*", searchString)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: format, pattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware that using `MATCHES[cd]` to perform regex (regular expression) matching is very expensive if you have a lot of data in your database.

You should try to avoid regular expressions if you can. And in this particular case it seems like using normalized text would allow you to use a predicate of the form `%K BEGINWITH[n] %@` or `%K ==[n] %@` wich is very fast.

To use normalized strings, you’d have both an attribute `text` and a normalized version of it, e.g. `textNormalized` which you could update in the setter for `text`. You’d then use `textNormalized` in the `[n]` predicates.

You can normalize text with

```swift
extension String {
    public var normalizedForSearch: String {
        let transformed = applyingTransform(
            StringTransform("Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; Lower"),
            reverse: false)
        return transformed as String? ?? ""
    }
}
```

Be sure to check the chapter on **Text** in our book: https://www.objc.io/books/core-data/ — it describes how to use normalized versions of your text to make sure searches like these are efficient.

Comment: ObjC.io has the best book on CoreData no dought, but do you think this answer the question in StackOverflow ?

Comment: ObjC.io has the best book on CoreData no dought, but do you think this answer the question in StackOverflow ?